# What exactly is 'workon' in virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I'm just starting with virtualenvwrapper, and got to exploring.  I hit a mystery that's bugging me.

There's this command 'workon' that works just as described, but I cannot figure out what it is:

'which workon' gives no output, so it appears not to be a script or executable.

'alias workon' cannot find it.

it does not appear to be a shell function.

There does not appear to be a file of that name anywhere.

So what is it exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ type -a workon
```

`workon` is a function